# Height of UICollectionViewCell with 2 multiline UILabels / self sizing collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` prototype which should look like this:

[image]

On the left side, there is a `UIImageView` which I centered vertically in and pinned it to the start of the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Next comes a title `UILabel` which I pinned to the top and end of the `UICollectionViewCell`. I also pinned it to the end of the `UIImageView`.

Below comes a detail `UILabel` which I pinned to the bottom of the title, the end of the `UICollectionViewCell` and constraint it to have the same width as the title.

Below that comes a description `UILabel` which I pinned to the bottom of the detail, the end of the `UICollectionViewCell` and the bottom of the `UICollectionViewCell`. It also has the same width as the title.

**What I want to achieve**

The title and description labels have 0 number of lines (multiline) because I don't know how many lines the labels will have at runtime.

Via my custom `UICollectionViewLayout` I provide the target width for the cell. Now I need to figure out, how height the cell must be for the given width.

I have a non visible `UICollectionViewCell` which I think I can use to calculate the sizes by setting the model from my datasource. But I have a problem.

**The Problem**

After I set the text of the labels in my "size calculation cell", what do I do with the width and what else do I have to do so I can let the auto layout system calculate a proper height for the cell which I can then return to my `UICollectionViewLayout`

Or in other words: how can I tell the cell to use the new width to calculate its height.

Comment: If I understood well, what you need is a way to calculate the height for the `UILabel` dinamically so you can add to your size calculation?

Comment: Since I set up constraints from top to bottom (cell top -> title -> detail -> description -> cell bottom) and left to right (cell start -> image -> labels -> cell end ), I hoped there was a way to say "hey cell, heres your width, how tall do you have to be so that none of the labels is truncated and all of them are visible?". I also already tried to calculate the height by myself by calling sizeThatFits(size) with the width and a CGFloat.max on the labels but they always return a height of 1 line even if with the text I set it is a 2 liner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems that I misunderstood how to use sizeThatFits. I now went with a different approach, though. This is what I did to get my self-sizing cells:

- I put the three labels in a vertical `UIStackView`
- I put the `UIImageView` and the `UIStackView` in a horizontal `UIStackView`
- I pinned to parent stack view to left, right, top and bottom of the cell where the bottom constraint is >= 0 instead of just = 0
- I use a protocol in my `UICollectionViewLayout` to ask for the height of a given width
- In my `UICollectionViewController`, I implement the protocol and where I register my cells, I also instantiate one of the cells which I use for measuring in the protocol function
- In the protocol, I first get the model object, then I hand down the model to my measuring cell which I keep in an instance variable in my view controller
- I then call getHeight(forWidth) on my cell. In this function, I set the cells `frame.size.height` to a very large number. Then I use AutoLayout to calculate the actual height (`setNeedsDisplay()`, `layoutIfNeeded()`)
- The height I need is the height of the parent stack view plus the margings

I hope this helps somebody like me in the future. [I also wrote a small blog post with some code samples of what I'm doing.](https://janthielemann.de/self-sizing-uicollectionviewcells-ios-10-swift-3/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this extension to the String:

```
extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

And then do this:

```
let heightOfLabel = self.string.height(withConstrainedWidth: labelWidth, font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)!)
```

You will get the height of the label with that font and that width. After that you can sum up the label heights and give it to the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the handy extension, I appreciate it. However, I wend with a different approach and now let AutoLayout handle the sizing for me. I'm not sure if your approach is more efficient with AutoLayout and UIStackView, I don't have to take care of checking all 3 labels if they have content. For example, I had wrong sizes of the cell when the bottom label was completely empty where as with UIStackView it now removes the label completely and still looks corret (check my other answer)

Comment: Thank you ! Will check it out @xxtesaxx